# How to extract password from Mac Mail, which isn't in the keychain

Tags: mac, email, password

I have an old gmail account to which I forgot the password. I have it setup in Mac Mail, and I can receive emails, but I forgot its password to login to the web interface.

All the internet research led me to retrieve the password from the keychain, but the problem is that its not there! Is there another way to extract the password, or to sniff it?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use Google's "Forgot Password" process? https://accounts.google.com/ForgotPasswd

Comment: Tried that, after answering the questions, it just loops back to asking the questions again. I guess I'm answering them wrong. As for recovery email address, it was my old university account which was deactivated a long time ago, and with no hopes of reactivating.

Comment: Are you certain that it isn't in any keychain on your system? Try: https://www.lifewire.com/recover-email-password-from-os-x-keychain-1174067

Comment: I have the same issue 4 years after the question was asked, I can't seem to find the answer. The password is the only way I can access the email account as there is no recovery option. Mail has the smtp password saved but it is not in the keychain.